# When will we use apt-get to download source?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

In what situation, will we like to use apt-get to download source?

Can's we install from binary installation by apt-get too?

If we are to install from source,   can't we download source from its website?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can download some package's source from their website, but by using apt you not only save time and energy, you know you are getting the *exact* version you would install from the binary. This is helpful if you want to mess around with specific versions.

Comment: what "you want to mess around with specific versions" mean?

Comment: You might want to try compiling that version on a different machine, look into a bug that only applies to that version and/or distribution, etc. I forgot to point out in the last comment that some distributions make changes to the upstream code before adding it to their repositories. In any case it is still *easy*.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get source` is extremely useful if you want to customize a package. Distributions already make several customizations (small if the package is already well-behaved) to every package in order to make it fit.

If you encounter a bug or want to add a feature to some program you're using, you shouldn't have to give up all bugfixes, features, and system integration that the distro package has already given you.